# Can't assign array using array member variable

Tags: arrays, excel, class, vba, object

I have a class where one of the member variables is an array.  I am trying to assign an array to the object but keep getting the 'Can't assign array' compile error.  Also I was curious as how to get UBound of the array in object.  UBound(obj.array) doesn't compile.  I am using excel 07 vba.

```
'Test routine that keeps failing

Sub test()  

Dim Arr(2) As String
Arr(0) = ""
Arr(1) = "Pizza"
Arr(2) = "Hoes"

Dim obj As Cats
Set obj = New Cats
obj.avry = Arr
obj.field = 4    
MsgBox UBound(obj.ary)

End Sub  


'Class declaration
Private pary() As String
Private pfield As Long

Public Property Get ary(ByVal index As Long) As String
    Set ary = pary(index)
End Property

Public Property Let avry(Value() As String)
    ReDim pary(UBound(Value)) As String
    For i = LBound(Value) To UBound(Value)
        pary(i) = Value(i)
    Next i
End Property

Public Property Get field() As Long
    field = pfield
End Property

Public Property Let field(Value As Long)
    pfield = Value
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    pfield = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with passing array parameters to class properties.

You can get around this by switching the Let parameter to a Variant:

```
Public Property Let avry(ByRef arrVal As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer
    If IsArray(arrVal) Then
        ReDim pary(LBound(arrVal) To UBound(arrVal))
        For i = LBound(arrVal) To UBound(arrVal)
            pary(i) = arrVal(i)
        Next i
    End If
End Property
```

Comment: tried your solution and am still getting the same error. I should mention i was getting a 'Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent' error before when I was using ary for both the get and let properties. Changed the get to avry as a workaround. Public Property Get ary(ByVal index As Long) As String Public Property Let ary(ByRef Value() As Variant) gives that error.  Maybe this has a connection with array assignment problem.

Comment: You should use different property names if the Let/Set and Get types are different (array vs. string in your case).  That's what your original 'inconsistent definitions' error was telling you. Note there's a problem with your Msgbox() call in test(): your property ary Get returns a string, but you're trying to treat it as an array by calling UBound() on the return value.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
Sub test()

Dim Arr(2) As String
Arr(0) = ""
Arr(1) = "Pizza"
Arr(2) = "Hoes"

Dim obj As Cats
Set obj = New Cats
obj.avry = Arr
obj.field = 4
MsgBox obj.ary(2)

End Sub

Public Property Get ary(ByVal index As Long) As String
    ary = pary(index)
End Property

Public Property Let avry(vValue As Variant)
    ReDim pary(UBound(vValue)) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(vValue) To UBound(vValue)
        pary(i) = vValue(i)
    Next i
End Property

Public Property Get field() As Long
    field = pfield
End Property

Public Property Let field(Value As Long)
    pfield = Value
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    pfield = 0
End Sub
```

As Tim said, you can pass the array as a variant.  Your MsgBox is trying to find a UBound of a String data type, so that was a problem.  Also, you weren't passing an argument to ary in the MsgBox.  The ary property returns a String, but you were using the Set keyword, which was another problem.

Comment: Thanks this worked.  Instead of using UBound, I added a third member variable that acts as a counter in the for loop of the assignment operator for the array.  Also I had to declare pary as pary()